# transition from a line from the start point to the end point in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a chart. I would like to see a point-by-point animation of the chart lines. my knowledge in d3.js is not enough. I've tried to encourage her but I do not know how to do it point to point. How can I do it?
an example is this:

https://jsfiddle.net/ej0wLtv6/

my code is this:

http://plnkr.co/edit/q6KkZjNDCozMUj5jdaKD?p=preview

```
city.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
    .style("stroke", function(d) { return z(d.id); })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the fiddle you have put as reference:

You can make the animation on the line like this:

```
//get all the lines 
city.selectAll(".line").each(function(d){
  //each line get the total length
  var totalLength = this.getTotalLength();
  //perform transition for line using dasharray and offset
    d3.select(this)
  .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
  .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
  .transition()
    .duration(2000)
  .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);

})
```

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/epNmpKnqhjx55ujVFnbx?p=preview)

Comment: you're amazing, taking advantage of your knowledge. I would like to add one more point in the chart (with a timeout maybe.), How could I add it and generate an animation of the new point?

Comment: not clear may be you can ask another question in so with explanation on wat you want to achieve

Comment: why do you use this totalLength? and "stroke-dasharray" can you help me with this please?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46257892/generate-an-animation-when-i-add-a-new-point-to-a-line-in-using-d3-js

Comment: Total length is for the total length of the path.
Its like saying the dashoffset in the array is equal to the total length of the path. then you make a transition which slowly makes it to 0, thus giving the animation to the path.

Comment: I researched and I could almost solve my problem but now I get a new one. Can you give me a hand, please?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46287131/the-line-is-repainted-in-d3-js